# How to use CompressionCodec in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, compression, mapreduce

I am doing following to do compression of o/p files from reducer:

```
OutputStream out = ipFs.create( new Path( opDir + "/" + fileName ) );
CompressionCodec codec = new GzipCodec(); 
OutputStream cs = codec.createOutputStream( out );
BufferedWriter cout = new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( cs ) );
cout.write( ... )
```

But got null pointer exception in line 3:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.zlib.ZlibFactory.isNativeZlibLoaded(ZlibFactory.java:63)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec.createOutputStream(GzipCodec.java:92)
    at myFile$myReduce.reduce(myFile.java:354)
```

I also got following [JIRA](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/hbase-issues/201202.mbox/%3C1886894051.6677.1329950151727.JavaMail.tomcat@hel.zones.apache.org%3E) for the same.

Can you please suggest if I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use the CompressionCodecFactory if you want to use compression outside of the standard OutputFormat handling (as detailed in @linker answer):

```
CompressionCodecFactory ccf = new CompressionCodecFactory(conf)
CompressionCodec codec = ccf.getCodecByClassName(GzipCodec.class.getName());
OutputStream compressedOutputSream = codec.createOutputStream(outputStream)
```

Answer (score 4):

You're doing it wrong. The standard way to do this would be:

```
TextOutputFormat.setOutputCompressorClass(job, GzipCodec.class);
```

The GzipCodec is a Configurable, you have to initialize it properly if you instantiate it directly (setConf, ...)

Try this and let me know if that works.